# How to add SteamVR assets in a Unity3D project to version control?

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, steamvr

I have a Unity3D project that uses SteamVR. Adding SteamVR support means adding 70MB of files to my project, and I don't want to check these in, as I think 70MB is way too much. I do want a reference checked in somewhere, as I am building in a CI pipeline.

For large binary assets I use Git LFS. As far as I know this doesn't work for an entire folder, only for files.

How can I somehow add this dependency (pinning my version) to Git, without tracking changes of 70MB of files?

Comment: 70mb is nothing, I've been using git with hundreds of megabytes total without using GitLFS and despite some slowness it works fine

Comment: Oh boy wait until you see artists commiting uncompressed textures lol. No for real. 70MB is absolutely reasonable for something as extensive as SteamVR. I'm not really sure why you consider this big.